# Debug exceptions in compiled GWT?

Tags: gwt

I was getting a NoSuchElementException in my GWT and I had no idea where it came from.

I've explored plenty of hints on how to get stack traces for exceptions in GWT, but got none to work. My solution's below (though I welcome any easier ways!)

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm on OS X Yosemite, running chrome version 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit), using GWT 2.7.0. I don't know if this will work for anything else.

My solution was eventually to put this code in, at the beginning of my onModuleLoad function:

```
native void openDebuggerWhenExceptionsCreated() /*-{
    window['captureStackTrace'] = function(throwable, reference) {
        debugger;
    };
}-*/;

public void onModuleLoad() {
    openDebuggerWhenExceptionsCreated();
    ...
```

Then run it in compiled javascript mode (with -style PRETTY), open the app in chrome, open the console (for me on mac, command + option + i) and then reproduce the error. If it hits the debugger; statement **while the console is open** then chrome's debugger will break there.

This works because when GWT creates an exception, it calls the captureStackTrace() function, which we replace here. It's still a mystery to me why that function existed if it does nothing, but either way, overwriting it seemed to be safe.

That `window['captureStackTrace']` is needed instead of just `captureStackTrace` because GWT actually changes the name of its own captureStackTrace if it sees us using a variable by that name.